# Activity restarts ofter picking an image from gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I´m making an app to order food and i get this weird behaviour when i try to upload an image to an item. I ´ve created an intent to open the gallery and until i´m picking the image it´s fine, but if i press the back button or select an image, the hole app starts again. I realized that if i press back again the old activity is still there but in the main menu fragment, the one that starts with the activity, not in the uploading fragment that was.
Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, your process will be killed if all of the memory of the device is taken up by another app (and the Camera app often *does* take up the entire memory of the device). How are you [saving your UI state](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states)? What does your 'old activity' do in `onCreate()`? Please include your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.